# CNContactPickerViewController: contact detail back button color

Tags: ios, cncontact

I link a simple [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0lnldt36u1a989/ContactsExample.zip?dl=0) to explain my problem.

In simple terms, I have a navigation controller based app with red theme and I have to pick email addresses from my contacts via `CNContactPickerViewController`.
[image: img 1]

My problem is with back bar button of contact detail view (red circle in image below): it appear white in a white background, so it is invisible.

[image: img 2]

How can i change the tint color of back bar button in the default one ( for contact detail view only)?

Comment: Did you find how to change the tint color ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. Please, answer my question if you'll find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's possible with a subclass of CNContactPickerViewController. Use `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white` in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to change the `UIBarButtonItem` `tintColor`in the contact detail view, so I solved the problem of white bar button color in white background restoring the default `UINavigationBar` `appearance` just before `CNContactPickerViewController` presentation and changing back to my custom `UINavigationBar` `appearance` when `CNContactPickerViewController` is dismissed.

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func openContacts(_ sender: Any) {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(value: false)
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        setupDefualtAppearance()
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func setupCustomAppearance() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 175.0/255.0, green: 22.0/255.0, blue: 28.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black
    }

    func setupDefualtAppearance() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = nil
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = nil
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = nil
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .default
    }

    func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
        setupCustomAppearance()
    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
        setupCustomAppearance()
    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
        setupCustomAppearance()
    }
}
```

I [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pkv1wqdyd4612l8/ContactsExample_workaround.zip?dl=0) a simple project to explain the workaround.

Comment: if you do not use UINavigationBar.appearance() in you project that solution will confuse nav bar colors across whole app.

Comment: @Argus if you do not use custom UINavigationBar.appearance() in you project you don't need to restore the default iOS UINavigationBar appearance and then you don't need this workaround.